# jQuery select a div with a certain class, that doesn't have another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="fuu">
  ...
</div>

<div class="fuu no">
  ...
</div>

...
```

How can I select all `fuu`'s besides the ones that have the `.no` class?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) to exclude the other class:

```
$('.fuu:not(.no)')
```

Comment: A little tidbit: `.fuu:not(.no)` is also a valid CSS3 selector, and will match the same elements on browsers that support `:not()`. Thus I believe jQuery will hand this selector to `querySelectorAll()` instead of relying on [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) for those browsers, thereby improving performance on those browsers. Not that anyone cares, of course :)

Comment: +1 from me on the nice extra tip, and with a +8 so far it seems that "some" developers do care about performance :-)

Comment: I couldn't get following to work: `$("#mydiv .fuu:not(.no)").click(function(){console.log('test');});` . I searched a long time for a problem related to `not()`, finally it was simply because the `active` class was added dynamically. I had to do it like this: `$("#mydiv").on('click', '.fuu:not(.no)', function(){console.log('test');});` . Since I kept digging 'round here, thinking `not()` was not working, I thought a comment here might help others.

Comment: if you need to exclude multiple classes, the syntax is like:  `$('.aaa:not(.bbb):not(.ccc)')`.  That will get everything that has class `aaa` but not class `bbb` *or* `ccc`

Answer (score 11):

You can also filter out the '.no' class with something like:

```
$('.fuu').not('.no');
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the first answer to work until I added another set of quotes. This gave me the desired result of selecting the class that excluded a second class.

```
$(".fuu:not('.no')").hide();
```

Answer (score -8):

get the div's class name, if it has a SPACE in the class name then it means it has more than one class !

Comment: And what if there was a `<div class="fuu yes">`? It doesn't have the `no` class, but it would return false for `.attr('class') == 'fuu'`.